# Plank not starting: cannot find libwnck-3.so.0

Tags: gnome, 21.04, plank

I'm running Ubuntu 21.04 and Gnome40.

Two days ago I read (on reddit) about gnome 40 and how to install it on Ubuntu. Since I have some issues with the stock desktop environment, I thought "why not give it a try". So I installed it and everything works fine.

While searching how to get the application-menu on the left hand side of the screen back, like it is in the stock environment, I came across plank (and the dash to plank gnome extension) which caught my eye. So I installed both and again it worked fine and looked awesome.

Today, however an update notifcation popped up and I updated and restarted my system. After that I noticed, that my docker / plank bar was gone. So I looked around and searchend and via terminal I found out, that plank wouldn't start because of following error:

```
plank: error while loading shared libraries: libwnck-3.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

After unsuccessfully searching the internet for some hours and trying different "solutions" like removing and installing again, forcing a reinstall, trying to install libwnck-3-0 and so on, I finally completely removed ubuntu from my pc, wiped both disks and did a fresh install. (Was overdue anyway).

But even with this fresh install, plank won't start due to the same error.

So if someone knows a solution to this problem I would highly appreciate it. :)

If you have further questions, please feel free to ask.

Thanks in advance.

---

Output of `apt-cache policy gnome-shell plank libwnck-3-0`:

```
gnome-shell:
  Installiert:           40.1-0shemgpubuntu2
  Installationskandidat: 40.1-0shemgpubuntu2
  Versionstabelle:
 *** 40.1-0shemgpubuntu2 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/shemgp/gnome-40/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     3.38.4-1ubuntu2 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 Packages
plank:
  Installiert:           0.11.89-3
  Installationskandidat: 0.11.89-3
  Versionstabelle:
 *** 0.11.89-3 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libwnck-3-0:
  Installiert:           1:40.0-1shemgpubuntu5
  Installationskandidat: 1:40.0-1shemgpubuntu5
  Versionstabelle:
 *** 1:40.0-1shemgpubuntu5 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/shemgp/gnome-40/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     3.36.0-1 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: Please add the output of `apt-cache policy gnome-shell plank libwnck-3-0` to the question.

Comment: Executed the command and edited my question with the output.

Comment: You have to try downgrading libwnck by `sudo apt-get install libwnck-3-0=3.36.0-1` . But it may end with GNOME 40 removal. Be careful.

Comment: Thank you very much, it's working again. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to reinstall the packages:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall plank libwnck-3-0=3.36.0-1
```

Answer (score 0):

Raffa states that: "Ubuntu 21.04 chooses Wayland by default and this can happen after an upgrade. Plank runs on X11."

you can check this answer in: [Plank is not working after upgrade to Hirsuite Hippo](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1341751/plank-is-not-working-after-upgrade-to-hirsuite-hippo)