# Plank is not working after upgrade to Hirsuite Hippo

Tags: command-line, gnome, themes, gtk, plank

I've used Plank before installing 21.04 Hirsuite Hippo. But now it is not working. And after uninstallation, I've reinstalled Plank. But I get this output in terminal:

```
$ plank
(plank:12385): Gtk-WARNING **: 14:04:43.852: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:9287:102: The :focused pseudo-class is deprecated. Use :focus instead.
(plank:12385): Gtk-WARNING **: 14:04:43.852: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:9292:114: The :focused pseudo-class is deprecated. Use :focus instead.
[CRITICAL 14:04:43.926827] [AbstractMain:255] Only X11 environments are supported.
```

I don't understand what this means:

```
Theme parsing error: gtk.css:9292:114: The :focused pseudo-class is deprecated. Use :focus instead.
```

What should I do to fix this problem?

Comment: In addition I upgraded to test mode of hirsuit hippo.

Comment: What do you mean by *upgraded to test mode of hirsute hippo* ; there is no test mode, so what do you mean?   (if you mean the *live* or *try* mode; how it relates after an install is not clear as it's a different thing)

Comment: Comments are for other than the op to ask questions. I suggest you add that information to your question as an [edit] at the same time as indicating which flavour of ubuntu you have upgraded from and to.

Comment: @guiverc I've upgraded 4 weeks ago to the development release.

Comment: Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll notice only supported releases of Ubuntu and flavors are on-topic for this site. For *impish* indri [21.10] questions you'll need to use a development support site such as IRC (#ubuntu+1) or Ubuntu Forums, or wait until after release for this site (expected release date for Ubuntu 21.10 is 14 October 2021 (https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/impish-indri-release-schedule/18540) when your question will be on-topic here).

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu 21.04 chooses Wayland by default and this can happen after an upgrade. Plank runs on X11.

To solve this, please log out your session and change to X11:

[How do you switch from Wayland back to Xorg in Ubuntu 17.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961304/how-do-you-switch-from-wayland-back-to-xorg-in-ubuntu-17-10)

Answer (score 0):

Gtk applications like to spit nonsensical messages on stdout. Usually that's due to programming errors; sometimes it's leftover debugging messages. One way or the other, there is usually nothing you as a user can do about it (other than redirecting them to `/dev/null`).

I consider that a major flaw of Gtk.